# Ejecutar consulta antes y después de un update

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla sencilla donde recupero los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
select id, price, description, reg_date from products;

+----+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | price | description                         | reg_date            |
+----+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 13.99 | Product 1                           | 2019-08-13 18:00:08 |
|  2 | 22.99 | Product 2                           | 2019-08-13 17:01:07 |
|  3 | 9.9   | Product 3                           | 2019-08-13 17:01:07 |
|  4 | 14.5  | Product 4                           | 2019-08-13 17:01:07 |
+----+-------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Me gustaría tener un *trigger* para que cuando se vaya a ejecutar un `update` del campo `price` se ejecute la consulta sobre el `id` respectivo.
El update lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE Product SET price = "13.99" WHERE price != "12.99" and id = "2";
```

Es decir, con el ID '2' y que el nuevo precio no coincida con el actual me actualizaría a uno nuevo.

Como puedo saber con el trigger que valor se ha ejecutado? es decir, puedo lanzar la select anterior pero poniendo como condición que busque por el "id"?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER product_update_after

AFTER INSERT ON Product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.price <=> OLD.price THEN
  ???
ENF ID
END

DELIMITER $$
```

Comment: Podrías postear lo que has probado?

Comment: No tengo el trigger creado. Quería saber como detectar el update y hacer luego la query que comento

Comment: Al crear uno es obligatorio que indiques si se ejecuta antes o después, por eso creo que ni miraste documentación ni lo has intentado.

Comment: aqui puedes documentarte https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php

Comment: No necesitas hacer un `SELECT` al `id` antes y después del `UPDATE`. Con ejecutar el trigger después del `UPDATE` tendrás en `OLD.price` el valor antiguo y en `NEW.price` el nuevo. Documentación: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Veo que has actualizado la pregunta agregando más información. ¿Comprobaste si mi respuesta es lo que necesitabas? PD: tu *trigger* de ejecutará **ANTES** de un `INSERT`, por lo que `NEW.id` aún no tendrá asignado un valor si es autonumérico y, además, en tu `AFTER INSERT ON Product` no habrá valores en `OLD` y sólo sirve para inserciones, no para modificaciones.

Comment: Pero puedo hacer una select en la tabla para saber que id es el que estoy modificando?

Comment: lo tengo! gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas hacer un `SELECT` al `id` antes y después del `UPDATE` para poder averiguar si el campo `price` cambió durante la modificación. Con ejecutar el iniciador (*trigger*) después del `UPDATE` tendrás en `OLD.price` el valor antiguo y en `NEW.price` el nuevo.

Documentación de interés: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html.

He aquí el entorno de pruebas que he usado para redactar esta respuesta:

```
-- Tabla principal
CREATE TABLE products (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  price float DEFAULT NULL,
  value float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- Datos de prueba
INSERT INTO products
  (id, name, price, value)
VALUES
  (1, 'Producto 1', 43, 2),
  (2, 'Producto 2', 12, 2);
-- Tabla de registro de cambios
CREATE TABLE log (
  texto text
);
```

La primera tabla es una reproducción de la tuya y la segunda es donde guardaremos un registro de modificaciones a través del siguiente iniciador (*trigger*):

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_log
  AFTER UPDATE ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.price != OLD.price THEN 
      INSERT INTO log VALUES
        (CONCAT(NEW.name, ': precio viejo: ', OLD.price, ', precio nuevo: ', NEW.price)); 
    END IF
```

El iniciador se ejecutará tras (`AFTER`) actualizar (`UPDATE`) el dato en la tabla `products`, por lo que tendremos los valores finales en `OLD` y `NEW`, pudiendo hacer con ellos lo que deseemos.

En mi caso inserto un registro de modificación en la tabla `log`:

```
UPDATE products SET price = price + 10;
SELECT * FROM log;
```

El resultado será:

```
Producto 1: precio viejo: 43, precio nuevo: 53
Producto 2: precio viejo: 12, precio nuevo: 22
```